# Failure to find dependency in proxies Maven repository

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

**The Maven Error:**

> Failed to execute goal on project XXXXXX: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project XXXXXX:XXXXXX:0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find
>   com.oracle.ucm:idcserver:jar:11.1.1.8 in
>   [http://internal-proxy:8080/nexus-2.6.4/content/groups/XXXXXX] was cached
>   in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the
>   update interval of internal-proxy has elapsed or updates are forced.

I have confirmed that the artifact has indeed been proxied from the external source.

Why can the local Maven build resolve the dependency in either the cloud or the intranet proxy?  How can I attempt to debug such problems?  I am administrator of the local Maven repository, so I can debug/change configuration suggested here.

Any insight would be welcomed.

Comment: Do you find the required dependency in your local repo?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this particular ucm jar with you ? The jar `com.oracle.ucm:idcserver:jar:11.1.1.8` is not there on maven central repository and thus will never be fetched since it does not exist there on maven central.

Last I remember, you will have to manually install it in your local repository. Check this post [here](https://github.com/tstirrat/ucm-twine/wiki/Installing-UCM-libraries)

Comment: I have installed it into the "3rd Party" portion of our Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, it was an improper URL in the settings.xml.

I wish the error was more transparent such as connection refused.

Comment: If at any point in time you are unable to understand the error maven is giving, try running it in debug mode `mvn -X install/pacakge/whatever`. Helps a lot !